# Append Images to FormData and get it in Array on .NET | Angular & .NET

Tags: .net, angular, form-data, iformfile

I append data to FormData in my Angular App by this way

```
const formData = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < this.cherry.Berry.length; i++) {
  if (this.cherry.Berry[i].Name !== undefined && this.cherry.Berry[i].Name) {
    formData.append('Berry[' + i + '][Name]', this.cherry.Berry[i].Name);
  }

  if (this.cherry.Berry[i].Description !== undefined && this.cherry.Berry[i].Description) {
    formData.append('Berry[' + i + '][Description]', this.cherry.Berry[i].Description);
  }

  if (this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain !== undefined && this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain !== null
    && this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain.length > 0) {
    for (let f = 0; f < this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain.length; f++) {
      formData.append('`Berry`[' + i + '][ImageList]', this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain[f]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
public class CherryDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Berry> Berry { get; set; }
}

public class Berry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> ImageList { get; set; }
}



[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCherry([FromForm] CherryDTO cherryDto)
    {
       return null
    }
```

In my backEnd I have a model

This example works good, I got everything in back end controller but ImageList null.
Basically it works good when I move ImageList to CherryDTO by this way

```html
public class CherryDTO
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<Berry> Berry { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile> ImageList { get; set; }
    }
```

And append for test by this way

```html
if (this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain !== undefined && this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain !== null
    && this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain.length > 0) {
    for (let f = 0; f < this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain.length; f++) {
      formData.append('ImageList', this.cherry.Berry[i].fileToUploadMain[f]);
    }
  }
```

In this way it works good. In my back end I get Files in array.
So the problem in `Berry[' + i + '][ImageList]`

But it works good with `Berry[' + i + '][Name]` and `Berry[' + i + '][Description]`

How I can fix it?

Comment: Because your `ImageList` is an array. Have you tried either: `'Berry[' + i + '][ImageList][' + f + ']'` or `'Berry[' + i + '].ImageList[' + f + ']'`?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I gave a solution. It work in this case `'Berry[' + i + '].ImageList`'.  Add the answer with this case and I will set it such a solution.